# Change the Privacy Status of a file using Google Drive Api and Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

How do I change the privacy status of a file using Google Drive Api and Python?
I can capture this state with `file['shared']` which returns a `boolean` 0 (*private*) or 1 (*public*)

Comment: In your situation, you are the owner of the file? And, where is the file? For example, it's in your Google Drive or a shared Drive?

Comment: I am the owner of the file and it is in my google drive

Comment: Doing this manually is very simple, you just go to +Share and then where it says Get Link you put Change and choose the Restricted option so that it remains private, But I need to do it from python

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: The code works perfectly for what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your current situation and your goal are as follows.

- You want to change `shared` of a file from `true` to `false` using pydrive for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values for a file using Google Drive API.
- You are the owner of the file, and the file is put in your Google Drive.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this script, all permissions except for the owner are deleted.

```py
ownerEmail = '###'  # Please set the owner's email address.
file_id = '###'  # Please set the file ID.
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) # Please your your authorization script.

file = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
permission_list = file.GetPermissions()
for obj in permission_list:
    if obj.get('emailAddress') != ownerEmail:
        file.DeletePermission(obj['id'])
```

Or, if the file is publicly shared and you want to delete only the publicly shared permission, you can use the following script.

```py
file_id = '###'  # Please set the file ID.
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth) # Please your your authorization script.
drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id}).DeletePermission('anyoneWithLink')
```

#### Reference:

- [Remove a Permission](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html?highlight=insertpermission#remove-a-permission)

Comment: Thank you very much you have helped me a lot, I spent many hours trying to solve this

Comment: @Tobias Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.